# When aggregating file descriptors, whats de difference between n<&- and n>&-

Tags: shell, aggregate, stdout, file-descriptor

If you look at [this documentation](http://abs.traduc.org/abs-5.1-fr/ch19.html), you will see that at the end of chapter 19.0 its saying that:

n<&- = close the file descriptor n (by default --> 0 --> stdin).

n>&- = close the file descriptor of exit n.

I don't get the difference between those two..
Closing a file descriptor should not be sensitive to the fact thats it is an exit FD like stdout, or not.

It would help me a lot if you could clarify this.
Much help needed, thanx in advance.

Comment: The ABS is a very poor choice of references, by the way. Please consider using either [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) or [the Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide); the ABS has a longstanding reputation for being infrequently maintained and often showcasing bad practices, if not including outright inaccuracies.

Answer (score 3):

The primary difference between these is that if no file descriptor number is specified, `>&-` closes stdout, whereas `<&-` closes stdin. In the use case given, where a file descriptor is specified by number, they are thus in practice entirely identical in shells presently available and in wide use.

However, the standard could be read to require `n<&-` to throw an error if the given file descriptor is not open for input, or `n>&-` to throw an error if the given file descriptor number is not open for output: *"If the digits in the word do not represent a file descriptor open for (input|output), a redirection error shall result"*. Thus, even if current widely-available shells do not in fact implement this enforcement, writing code to be robust in the scenario where enforcement is present may be wise.

---

See [the relevant POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), with emphasis added below:

> #### 2.7.5 Duplicating an Input File Descriptor
>
> The redirection operator:
>
> ```
> [n]<&word
> ```
>
> shall duplicate one input file descriptor from another, or shall close one. If word evaluates to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by `n`, or standard input if `n` is not specified, shall be made to be a copy of the file descriptor denoted by word; *if the digits in word do not represent a file descriptor already open for input, a redirection error shall result*; see [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_08_01). **If word evaluates to '-', file descriptor `n`, *or standard input if `n` is not specified*, shall be closed.** Attempts to close a file descriptor that is not open shall not constitute an error. If word evaluates to something else, the behavior is unspecified.
>
> #### 2.7.6 Duplicating an Output File Descriptor
>
> The redirection operator:
>
> ```
> [n]>&word
> ```
>
> shall duplicate one output file descriptor from another, or shall close one. If word evaluates to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n, or standard output if n is not specified, shall be made to be a copy of the file descriptor denoted by word; *if the digits in word do not represent a file descriptor already open for output, a redirection error shall result*; see [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_08_01). **If word evaluates to '-', file descriptor `n`, *or standard output if `n` is not specified,* is closed.** Attempts to close a file descriptor that is not open shall not constitute an error. If word evaluates to something else, the behavior is unspecified.